# SharePoint 2010 Custom Search Application: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

Since a few days, i get this Error Message while searching in my custom search webpart: 
The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.

I checked the SharePoint LOG-Folder and found the following error to this message: 
SearchServiceApplicationProxy::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault]: The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault).

I got a second webpart searching just one part of the application which is working properly. I think the problem has to do with a misfunction or misconfiguration of the SharePoint Search Service since the search has always been working before.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I tried several solutions:

- Resetting Search Index
- Full Crawl
- Rebooting SharePoint Server

I actually don't know what the problem was. For another task, I had to redeploy one custom solution (which didn't have anything to do with the search-webpart). This fixed the issue!